# Verificar se a string é nula ou vazia

Tags: java, android, string

Como eu faço para verificar se a minha variável é vazia ou nula?

```
// Inserção
Nome = tf_Nome.getText().toString();
Tipo = tf_Tipo.getText().toString();
Estoque = Integer.valueOf(tf_Estoque.getText().toString());         
Preco = Double.valueOf(tf_Preco.getText().toString());
```

---

Não estou sabendo fazer como faço para que ele verifique se o Estoque e Preco são em branco ou nulo...

```
} else if(Nome != null && Tipo != null && **Estoque < 0 && Preco < 0**) {
    Estoque = 0;
    Preco = 0;

    BaseDados.InserirProdutos(Nome, Tipo, Estoque, Preco);
    Limpar();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Produto" +Nome+ " Adicionado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vou supor que a linguagem que você usa aí é Java.

Você já sabe comparar com nulo (por exemplo, `Nome != null`). Se a *string* não é nula, você pode ver seu comprimento através de seu [método length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()).

Por exemplo:

```
int tamanho = Nome.length() // isso preenche tamanho com o comprimento de Nome.
```

Existe também o método [isEmpty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) que retorna `true` se a string for vazia, e `false` caso contrário. Acho mais legível para o seu caso.

Você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
public Boolean isStringUsable(string s) {
    return s != null && !s.isEmpty(); // lembre-se de que a comparação
                                      // com nulo sempre deve vir antes,
                                      // para evitar chamar métodos em instâncias nulas
}
```

O código acima é para o caso em que você quer variáveis preenchidas **e** não nulas. Se você quer o contrário, variáveis vazias **ou** nulas, é só fazer o negativo do que fiz acima:

```
public Boolean isNullOrEmpty(string s) {
    return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}
```

E passar suas strings para esse método.

Comment: @renan valeu :) próxima vez edita o post, toda ajuda é sempre bem-vinda ;)

Answer (score 2):

Quando for realizar essa verificação em Strings, no Android utilize sempre o método isEmpty() da classe TextUtils do Android.

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(suaString);
```